# Different values for cancel and empty input on prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

I've just started with Javascript and I been trying to make a little script that says hello. Here it is:

```
function hello() {

    while (!name) {

        var name = prompt("What's your name", "");
        var greetingElement = document.getElementById("greeting");

        greetingElement.style.color = "red";

        if (name == null) {
            greetingElement.innerHTML = "Boring!";
            break;
        }
        else if (name == 0) {
            greetingElement.innerHTML = "Don't you have a name";
        }
        else {
            greetingElement.innerHTML = "Hello " + name + "!";
        }
    }
}
window.onload = hello;
```

My problem is that I want to show one message if you press cancel on the prompt and a different if you don't enter a input and press OK. So far as I can understand both of those actions result in the value null, so how can I show a different message?

What I've done in my code clearly isn't optimal I know that.

I also want the while loop to end if you press cancel which it doesn't now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to check some different falsy values, you need to compare them with [`Strict equal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) operator. You can see it in the code below. I've also made some minor changes to your code to get it work fluently.

```
function hello(){
    var greetingElement = document.getElementById("greeting");
    greetingElement.style.color = "red";
    while (!name) {
        var name = prompt("What's your name?", "");
        if (name === null || name === false) { // Canceled
            greetingElement.innerHTML = "Boring!";
            break; // Leave this out, if the name is mandatory
        }
        if (name === "") { // OK, but no name
            greetingElement.innerHTML = "Don't you have a name?";
        } else { // OK with a name
            greetingElement.innerHTML = "Hello " + name + "!";
        }
    }
}
```

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4T6wA/)

Comment: Thank you! Works really nice and I get it!